# Thread nullpointerException QuickBlox "muc + chat"

Tags: java, multithreading, chat

I have a problem with the API QUICKBLOX, when I put "MUC" I jump rather strange error, and I don't know why.

```
public class MyChatController {

// ================= QuickBlox ===== Step 8 =================
// Get QuickBlox chat server domain.
// There will be created connection with chat server below.
public static final String CHAT_SERVER = QBChat.getChatServerDomain();

private XMPPConnection connection;

private ConnectionConfiguration config;
private Chat chat;
// Multi-User Chat, también conocido como
// MUC, es un robusto protocolo de conferencia basado en XMP. 
// Fue desarrollado como un sistema de chat en grupo para extender 
// la funcionalidad de clientes Jabber/XMPP, cuyo protocolo sólo permite 
// establecer conferencias entre 2 personas. Ha sido acogido como propuesta 
// de extensión XEP-0045, y se ha incluido de forma nativa en el programa servidor ejabberd.
private MultiUserChat muc2;

private String chatLogin;
private String password;
private String friendLogin;

private ChatManager chatManager;
   public MyChatController(String chatLogin, String password) {
    this.chatLogin = chatLogin;
    this.password = password;
}

public void startChat(String buddyLogin) {
    this.friendLogin = buddyLogin;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Chat action 1 -- create connection.
            Connection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
            config = new ConnectionConfiguration(CHAT_SERVER);
            connection = new XMPPConnection(config);

            try {
                connection.connect();
                connection.login(chatLogin, password);

                // Chat action 2 -- create chat manager.
                chatManager = connection.getChatManager();

                // Chat action 3 -- create chat.
                chat = chatManager.createChat(friendLogin, messageListener);

                // Set listener for outcoming messages.
                chatManager.addChatListener(chatManagerListener);

                // Muc 2 
                muc2 = new MultiUserChat(connection, "2387_chat1@muc.chat.quickblox.com");
                // Discover whether user3@host.org supports MUC or not

                // The room service will decide the amount of history to send
                muc2.join(chatLogin);
                muc2.invite(friendLogin, "Welcome!");
                Log.d("friendLogin ->",friendLogin);
                // Set listener for outcoming messages.
                //chatManager.addChatListener(chatManagerListener);
                muc2.addMessageListener(packetListener);
                addListenerToMuc(muc2);
                //chat1@muc.chat.quickblox.com    ---  el meu
                Message message = new Message(friendLogin + "@muc.chat.quickblox.com");
                message.setBody("Join me for a group chat!");
                message.addExtension(new GroupChatInvitation("2387_chat1@muc.chat.quickblox.com"));
                connection.sendPacket(message);

            } catch (XMPPException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

/*** muc */
private void addListenerToMuc(MultiUserChat muc){
    if(null != muc){
        muc.addMessageListener(new PacketListener() {

            @Override
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                Log.i("processPacket", "receiving message");
                }
        });
    }
}    

PacketListener packetListener = new PacketListener() {
    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
      Message message = (Message)packet;
      try {
        muc2.sendMessage(message);
    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      //System.out.println("got message " + message.toXML());
    }
};  


private PacketInterceptor packetInterceptor = new PacketInterceptor() {

    @Override
    public void interceptPacket(Packet packet) {
         System.out.println("Sending message: " + packet.toString());
         Message message = muc2.createMessage();
         message.setBody("Hello from producer, message " +
                " ");
         try {
            muc2.sendMessage(message);
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};

/***/
```

ERRORS  :

```
05-20 23:16:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(3361): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-277
05-20 23:16:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(3361): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-20 23:16:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(3361):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat$1.connectionCreated(MultiUserChat.java:114)
05-20 23:16:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(3361):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.initConnection(XMPPConnection.java:607)
05-20 23:16:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(3361):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connectUsingConfiguration(XMPPConnection.java:556)
05-20 23:16:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(3361):     at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.connect(XMPPConnection.java:984)
05-20 23:16:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(3361):     at com.quickblox.sample.chat.MyChatController$5.run(MyChatController.java:73)
05-20 23:16:19.679: E/AndroidRuntime(3361):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-20 23:16:19.807: E/Trace(3445): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: Your stack trace says `at com.quickblox.sample.chat.MyChatController$5.run(MyChatController.java:73)`.  Which is line 73?  That will tell you where the error occurred, and it will give you a big clue as to what is `null` here.

Comment: This is my line 
  connection.connect();

works fine, but when I leave the activity to go after i re-enter to talk to the user, I skipped nullpointer.

Answer (score 1):

Dropbox example:  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2239636/java.txt but throw ThreadNullPointerException  or error XML.

This is error XML: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2239636/errors.txt

If I use the other android-smack - x I get:

```
05-21 18:16:17.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2352): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 18:16:17.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2352): java.lang.VerifyError: com/quickblox/sample/chat/MyChatController
05-21 18:16:17.409: E/AndroidRuntime(2352): at com.quickblox.sample.chat.ChatActivity.onCreate(ChatActivity.java:81)
```

Now have error  :

```
05-21 23:30:32.075: W/System.err(2579): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 23:30:32.075: W/System.err(2579):     at org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat$1.connectionCreated(MultiUserChat.java:115)
```

Here is the problem, but I don't know this code:

http://www.code.google.com/p/asmack/issues/detail?id=13

Solved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Smack configuration is not initialized properly. This is a known issue and is reported [here](http://code.google.com/p/asmack/issues/detail?id=13), [here](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-315) and explained [here](http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/128477#128477).

Comment: I see, but android-smack7, quickBlox came with the api, it is very difficult to change something.

I do not know what to do.

Comment: did you try to initialize configuration (`SmackConfiguration.getVersion();
`) before you create connection?

Comment: without the "MUC" not as access to quickblox room, with "MUC" if I can.

Comment: any alternative to muc?  http://www.massapi.com/class/mu/MultiUserChat.html   or.... la variable "chat" puede passar el room de alguna manera ? :S

Comment: sorry, i don't know spanish. have you tried to put SmackConfiguration.getVersion(); call to your class as advised here: http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/128477#128477 ?